# php 64bit integer overflow differs from Java implmention

Tags: java, php, random

I am trying to implement Java's Random class in php and after a long couple of hours I found that php returns a different value to that of java when multiplying two 64bit longs together.

In php

```
echo (int) (160577175182 * 25214903917);
```

gives

```
9101091335015235584
```

In a Java applet

```
g.drawString( "Java: " + (160577175182L * 25214903917L), 10, 10 );
```

gives

```
Java: 9101091335015183990
```

Interestingly if you put it into calc in programmer mode it also produces 9101091335015183990.

25214903917 is the java random magic number 0x5DEECE66D

160577175182 is a test seed value

I am aware the resulting number is larger than a 64 bit number and therefore the results from both are incorrect. I just need to be able to replicate the java result in php.

Comment: Is it relevant? [If the float is beyond the boundaries of integer (usually +/- 2.15e+9 = 2^31 on 32-bit platforms and +/- 9.22e+18 = 2^63 on 64-bit platforms other than Windows), the result is undefined, since the float doesn't have enough precision to give an exact integer result. No warning, not even a notice will be issued when this happens!](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.integer.php#language.types.integer.casting.from-float)

Comment: yes no warnings or notice is the main reason why I lost time on this and no doubt the cause of frustration to many

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the great insight of mrVoid

```
private function java_multi($large_a,$large_b)
{
    $mul_str = bcmul($large_a,$large_b);
    $hex = $this->dec2hex($mul_str);
    $hex = substr($hex,-16);
    return (int) $this->hex2dec($hex);
}
```

With thanks to [joost](http://php.net/manual/en/function.dechex.php)

```
function dec2hex($number)
{
    $hexvalues = array('0','1','2','3','4','5','6','7',
               '8','9','A','B','C','D','E','F');
    $hexval = '';
     while($number != '0')
     {
        $hexval = $hexvalues[bcmod($number,'16')].$hexval;
        $number = bcdiv($number,'16',0);
    }
    return $hexval;
}

// Input: A hexadecimal number as a String.
// Output: The equivalent decimal number as a String.
function hex2dec($number)
{
    $decvalues = array('0' => '0', '1' => '1', '2' => '2',
               '3' => '3', '4' => '4', '5' => '5',
               '6' => '6', '7' => '7', '8' => '8',
               '9' => '9', 'A' => '10', 'B' => '11',
               'C' => '12', 'D' => '13', 'E' => '14',
               'F' => '15');
    $decval = '0';
    $number = strrev($number);
    for($i = 0; $i < strlen($number); $i++)
    {
        $decval = bcadd(bcmul(bcpow('16',$i,0),$decvalues[$number{$i}]), $decval);
    }
    return $decval;
}
```

This

java_multi(160577175182,25214903917)

returns

9101091335015183990

Same as the java.

Answer (score 3):

I did some tests using extended arithmetic classes in Java, and reached the following conclusions:

The PHP result is consistent with doing the multiplication on unrounded inputs in integer form, but then converting the result to 64-bit floating point.

All numbers in the following results are in hexadecimal, because it is easier to see what is going on.

The full product is db7e4d92597bf73676

The product rounded to IEEE 754 64-bit floating point is db7e4d92597bf80000

The Java result is 7e4d92597bf73676, the least significant 64 bits of the full product.

The PHP product is 7e4d92597bf80000, the least significant 64 bits of the integer value of the double conversion of the product.

I am not a PHP expert. Does PHP have an extended integer data type or library? To get the correct result the low order 64 bits have to be extracted from the product without converting to floating point first.

Comment: Thank you for your time, as a new user I can not up vote your answer, else I would have. There are modules bcmath [link](http://php.net/manual/en/book.bc.php) and GMP. Using the bcmul function you can get the product as a integer string. I suppose that what I should work with using your insight.

Answer (score 0):

The correct result is: [4048938043477406987894](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=160577175182*25214903917)

It is a 72 bit number. So there is an overflow.

The Java part is correct `4048938043477406987894 mod (2^64) = 9101091335015183990`

The php implementation is probably rounding off by `PHP_INT_MAX` and should give `9101091335015184428`

So my guess is to check for PHP_INT_MAX and use it as a for JAVA implementation.

It might be also `echo (int) (160577175182 * 25214903917);` is different from `echo (int) (int)160577175182 * (int)25214903917;`

Comment: The echos are the same as per your closing suggestion. the cast as int is required as php puts the result into a float that is the approximate 64bit. Without any cast the result is 4.0489380434774E+21. It is this that what is causing the differing value. I can get the correct answer as a string using php function bcmul (160577175182 , 25214903917) but then what should I do?